# Axis 1.4 Axis :Admin tools error while trying to deploy the service using maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, axis

I am trying to deploy an axis 1.4 service using deploy.wsdd and maven axis tools plugin,
I have configured the pom.xml but getting error where it needs `inputFiles`.
Please refer my POM below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-service</id>
          <goals>
          <goal>admin</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
           <inputFiles>
            <inputFile>/src/main/resources/config/axis/deploy.wsdd</inputFile>
            <inputFile>/src/main/resources/configaxis/undeploy.wsdd</inputFile>
          </inputFiles>
          <isServerConfig>true</isServerConfig>
          <configOutputDirectory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</configOutputDirectory>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am getting error where I am setting the inputFiles (Which is ArrayList type according to the documentation). Please let me know what is problem with this setting and find the error below

**Command :**

`mvn clean axistools:admin`

**Error :**

```
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'axistools:admin'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'axistools-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <inputFiles>VALUE</inputFiles>
</configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-DinputFile=VALUE'
```

Please let me know what is the value I need to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the pom file as follows and it worked

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
     <configuration>
           <inputFiles>
            <inputFile>/src/main/resources/config/axis/deploy.wsdd</inputFile>
            <inputFile>/src/main/resources/configaxis/undeploy.wsdd</inputFile>
          </inputFiles>
          <isServerConfig>true</isServerConfig>
          <configOutputDirectory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</configOutputDirectory>
     </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-service</id>
          <goals>
          <goal>admin</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But there was another problem, I have to give full path in the `inputFile` and did not add the file for undeploying the web service.
The plugin executed the AdmitClient, but the problem was that it could not create server-config.wsdd as it could not find the compiled class files. Basically the java are located in `src/main/java` and compiled to `target/classes` . 
I am still figuring out how to rectify this problem..
There is not much documentation about this plugin

Comment: hey, I've the same error right know... did you find a solution?

Comment: I used ANT script in Maven... I was not able to solve it... If you could find a solution please let me know... I can also provide you solution through ANT

Comment: See this issue (still unresolved) : _axistools:admin does not include target/classes in classpath_ [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAXISTOOLS-3](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAXISTOOLS-3)

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get the admin goal to work for some hours now, without luck.
The project classpath is not available when running it.
I ended up using the antrun plugin to do this instead.